# XPages REST Service's "keys" property - how to use dynamic value

Tags: javascript, rest, xpages

I have a REST service that uses a categorized view.  I am trying to get the "keys" property to work with a non-hardcoded value.  I get the "Sorry, an error occurred" message when I try to use any Javascript.

This is the only way it works:

```
<xe:restService id="rsVictims" pathInfo="gridDataVictims">
    <xe:this.service>
        <xe:viewItemFileService defaultColumns="true"
            viewName="InvoiceMPRVictims" contentType="application/json"
            keys="k28ts71zrjsw">
            <xe:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:applicationScope.get("appConfig").keywords.appDataStore.join("!!")}]]></xe:this.databaseName>
        </xe:viewItemFileService>
    </xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>
```

I have tried returning a value with SSJS:

```
    <xe:restService id="rsVictims" pathInfo="gridDataVictims">
        <xe:this.service>
            <xe:viewItemFileService defaultColumns="true"
                viewName="InvoiceMPRVictims" contentType="application/json">
                <xe:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:applicationScope.get("appConfig").keywords.appDataStore.join("!!")}]]></xe:this.databaseName>
                <xe:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
var keyValue = doc.getItemValueString("grantID");
return keyValue;}]]></xe:this.keys>
            </xe:viewItemFileService>
        </xe:this.service>
    </xe:restService>
```

I have also tried moving that SSJS into a function and calling that:

```
<xe:restService id="rsVictims" pathInfo="gridDataVictims">
    <xe:this.service>
        <xe:viewItemFileService defaultColumns="true"
            viewName="InvoiceMPRVictims" contentType="application/json"
            keys="#{javascript:getMPRRESTKey();}">
            <xe:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:applicationScope.get("appConfig").keywords.appDataStore.join("!!")}]]></xe:this.databaseName>
        </xe:viewItemFileService>
    </xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>
```

Here is the getMPRRESTKey() function:

```
function getMPRRESTKey() {  
    var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
    var keyValue = doc.getItemValueString("grantID");
    return keyValue;
}
```

The only way it works is to "hardcode" a value in the keys property.

Any help would be great on this!

Thanks!

Comment: Dan, I had similar issues two months ago.  I found the viewFileItemService to act strangely.  The viewJsonService works much better.  I wrote a blog post on this back then that might be of some help.  It doesn't specifically address your issue, but it might help.  http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/07/creating-updatable-rest-service-for-use.html

Comment: @Steve - I see the keys property sample in the article.  I tried this for the keys: `<xe:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:return currentDocument.getDocument().getItemValueString("grantID");}]]></xe:this.keys>` -- but that still gave me an error.  What does "myBean" look like?  Are you using an actual bean or just a Java class?  Sorry -- not that proficient at Java just yet...

Comment: If I remember right I was using a POJO, although it shouldn't matter it is just SSJS calling java.  It does prove that you can put code there.  A few things you can try:  1) Make sure you also don't have a category filter (you don't appear to have one), this causes an error with viewItemFileService  2) Before page load try setting value in scoped variable, it is possible that it doesn't allow you to reference currentDocument in that context  3) Change the REST type to viewJsonService, and use the Category filter instead of Keys.  Let me know if any of those work.

Comment: @Steve -- it was a viewScope variable that works with the keys property -- thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me (thanks to Steve Zavocki) was to pass a viewScope variable to the keys property:

```
<xe:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.get("myKeysValue");}]]></xe:this.keys>
```